# Strange characters in semantic ui message?

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I've applied the form validation where missing input will be reflected in error message. The code works fine when I tested in localhost:

[image]

But after I uploaded my code to heroku and preview it, the message still works but instead showing some strange characters:

[image]

The message div is placed within the form div, any idea about this weird issue?

```
<div className="ui error message"></div>
```

Edit: Here's the html file that I used.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='root'></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML where these messages are displayed please and any script which is used to add them? If you are adding the bullets as characters manually I suspect a character encoding issue.

Comment: @Lew, is that because of missing charset attribute in meta tag?

Comment: You could try adding one, unfortunately I won't be at a computer to try it for myself for a couple of hours or so.

Comment: @Lew, thanks it works now!

Answer (score 0):

save  your document in format UTF WITH BOM ;)